# School assignment: Generating 7 random numbers, putting them into an array, and making sure each number is unique

Tags: java, arrays, random

So, I have to make a program where I have 7 random numbers and then I have to put them into an array. Each number in the array cannot be the same as another number in the array. I wrote a program which does this, however it only works some of the time. When it does work, it works perfectly, and when it doesn't work, the program just runs forever and I have to force stop it.

I can't seem to find my mistake. Please help!

Here is my code:

```
package arraysex2;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ArraysEx2 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        Random r=new Random();
        int random,count=0,count2;
        boolean isRepeat=false;
        Integer[]randoms=new Integer[7];

        while(count<=randoms.length-1){
            random=r.nextInt(30)+1;
            for(count2=0;count2<count;count2++){
                if(random==randoms[count2]){
                    isRepeat=true; 
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!isRepeat){ 
              randoms[count]=random;
              count++; 
            }   
        }
        for(count=0;count<=randoms.length-1;count++){
            System.out.print(randoms[count]+" ");
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: `int[] randoms = IntStream.generate(() -> r.nextInt(30) + 1).distinct().limit(7).toArray();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in how you are handling `isRepeat` once it gets set to true. Trace it after that point to figure out how the while loop terminates. The times when it works is because `isRepeat` never gets set to true.

In general, when loops don't terminate, it is a useful debugging tip to look at what is supposed to cause it to terminate and see why those conditions don't change or aren't met.

Comment: Thank you so much! I fixed it by adding 'isRepeat=false;' right after the while loop begins.

Answer (score 0):

You should reinitialize `isRepeat` every time the while loop is repeated.

```
...
 while(count<=randoms.length-1){
            isRepeat = false // HERE
            random=r.nextInt(30)+1;
            for(count2=0;count2<count;count2++){
                if(random==randoms[count2]){
                    isRepeat=true; 
                    break;
                }
...
```

I hope this is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem, as @Prisoner mentioned. Thanks for the feedback!